# Django File upload in model

Tags: python, django

Considering that we`ve got the model below:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    file1 = models.FileField(upload_to='projects/', blank =True)
    file2 = models.FileField(upload_to='projects/', blank =True)
    file3 = models.FileField(upload_to='projects/', blank =True)
    file4 = models.FileField(upload_to='projects/', blank =True)
    file5 = models.FileField(upload_to='projects/', blank =True)
```

How many file1 can we create? If I want to create severals files, I usually write my code this way:

```
class File1(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='projects/', blank =True)
```

Instead to create severals models File1, File2, File 3, Is there a way to upload several file1 in Django using only the model Project? I mean to not have to create a model for each file1, file2, file3 if we need to upload several of them.

Many Thanks,

Comment: You can use [Many-to-many relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)

Comment: as far as i know, the way you have is the easiest ,but if you want another way take a look at this https://qasimalbaqali.medium.com/upload-multiple-images-to-a-post-in-django-ff10f66e8f7a#:~:text=body%20%3D%20forms.,%3D%22Item%20Description.%22)&text=Now%20this%20is%20the%20most,formsets%20to%20make%20this%20happen.

Comment: Thank you for this